# Linux antivirus and files bigger than 4GB

Tags: linux, antivirus

I wish to scan files that are bigger than 4GB, such as video files.

I noticed many antivirus programs are limited to a maximum of 4GB (ClamAV for example).

So:

- Is there an antivirus software that allow scanning of files bigger than 4GB?
- If not, is there a work-around that will allow me to pass this limitation?

Update: as suggested by @Purefan, I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-devel/issues/45) at ClamAV

Comment: I think this is because most are written in 32 bit and so the maximum size is 4GB which can be used. I am not sure which tools are fully 64 bit and can scan larger files.

Comment: @DanielRuf My thought exactly. I guess michael could download the source code and try to compile for 64 bit, or file a bug here https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-devel/issues

Comment: 32-bit executables can definitely scan files larger than 4GB. `mmap` takes an offset of type `off_t` (which is 64-bit) to specify where in the file you want to map from. The process can't map more than about 2.8GB at once, but it can definitely unmap and remap the next chunk. The equivalent in Windows is `MapViewOfFile` which also accepts a 64-bit offset. If instead the AV wishes to use traditional file functions (e.g. `fopen`) then they can define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` and use `fseek64`. Any restriction to 4GB by the AV is not due to technical restrictions of the operating system.

Comment: I answered something similar in SuperUser [here](https://superuser.com/questions/956128/what-does-this-clamav-message-mean/956129#956129).

Comment: If it were simply the file size limit then it would be trivial to recompile the code with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`. However given the way AV detection works it is likely they are maintaining a pointer as a 32 bit unsigned integer rather a `off_t` type..

Comment: (which is more or less what Polynomial says above) But IIRC, `off_t` is only in the more recent POSIX stds - so they may have good reasons. But even in 2015 why are you running a 32-bit OS? (I'd be very *very* suprised if a 64-bit system was similarly affected - assuming we're not talking about the panotify issue here)

Answer (score -1):

I have never tried myself, but checking in `clamd.conf` file I can see that the size of files can be set manually.

Changing the following values to "n" appears to be the workaround for the file size limit which sets it to unlimited:

```
-max-filesize=#n 
-max-scansize=#n 
BytecodeUnsigned yes

http://blog.clamav.net/2014/11/brief-re-introduction-to-clamav.html
```

However, I know that currently ClamAV has hard file limit to 4GB. However, from my understanding by setting to "n" along with `BytecodeUnsigned` to "yes" in config file will do the workaround and of course there are a few particulars to consider before doing that, particulars such as:

> - the amount of memory present/available on server should be way bigger than the file size because ClamAV is mapping the file into memory.
> - The swap file system, the size of swap fs should be calculated according to the ram size on server (just in case it hits the swap).

If the above to particular are not taken care of it with an extra attention ClamAV won't be able to scan or better, it will eat all of systems memory and therefore killed by OEM Killer.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this info?

Comment: `the amount of memory present/available on server should be way bigger than the file size because ClamAV is mapping the file into memory.` This statement is not true. You definitely can map a file into memory that's way larger than the amount of memory the machine has available. The size limit to mapped file is the virtual address space, rather than the amount of available memory.

Comment: As @LieRyan says, mapping something into memory does not require actually _allocating_ memory. I can easily map a 50 GiB file on a system with literally 32 MiB of physical memory.